# fancytree folders never collapse

Tags: fancytree

fancytree folders are never collapsed. All children and parents are displayed without correct nesting structure.

When I copy the exact same data that works in text data source, instead from a web2py (python) controller the folders will not collapse but just display permanently expanded. No js console errors in browser.

original data that works perfectly in text file

FancyTree copies data from python contoller like this

```
json_list = [{
  "alexLink": "http://example.com/",
  "kind": "tasks#task",
  "id": "MTYwNzEzNjc2OTEyMDI1MzcwNzM6ODUwNjk4NTgzOjExMTkyODk2MjA",
  "etag": "\"4qyCALf1j510T_-I20NAMbUHF2k/LTEzNTgzMTMzODg\"",
  "title": "Task 01",
  "updated": "2015-04-23T19:25:44.000Z",
  "selfLink": "",
  "position": "00000000002147483647",
  "status": "needsAction"
}]
```

I convert to json:  `json_list = json.dumps(json_list)`

Then use as source:

```
// Initialize Fancytree
$("#alexTree").fancytree({
    checkbox: true,
    selectMode: 3,
    source: {{=XML(json_list)}},
    postProcess: function(event, data){
        data.result = convertData(data.response);
    },
    select: function(event, data) {
        window.open(data.node.data.alexLink, "_blank");
```

Data looks same as in text file source. What could be causing the folders to not contract with children under them?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an obvious reason, why your sample is not working (I assume persistence extension is off?).
Except maybe for `{{=XML(json_list)}}`, that may do something unexpected.
I guess a debuggable demo is needed, to find out.

Anyway, your sample does this:

1. Generate tree data in a native (none-Fancytree) format
2. Generate a html page with an embedded `<script>` tag that in turn has this data embedded as string
3. On page-load the tree is created with native data and post processing is done client-side

Fancytree was designed with this pattern in mind (among others):

1. Have a static page with an empty `<div id="tree">` element and include some JavaScript
2. On page-load initialize the tree and pass an ajax url for `source`.
    This will immediately display the page for your users, while loading is deferred (showing a spinning icon)
3. A soon as the data arrives, the tree will update.
    (You could also consider to do the conversion server-side and send valid Fancytree-compatible data.)

This would probably deliver a smoother user experience. It would also allow to refresh tree data without reloading the page, by calling `tree.reload()`.

Comment: you're suggestion worked Martin.  Thanks

var tree_url = "{{=URL(c='default/view_tree.json', vars=dict(specificTaxonomyFK=specificTaxonomyFK))}}";

source: {url: tree_url},

view_tree.json does an include of the data